# ClientSession cannot be serialized to BSON - Mongodb Transaction

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm fairly new to mongodb transaction so I have no idea what I did wrong. I've followed the direction in the documentation but I still get this error

```
{
"status": 400,
"name": "Error",
"message": "ClientSession cannot be serialized to BSON."
}
```

Here's my code

```
    async createInsurance(params) {
    const session = await db99.startSession();
    try {
      session.startTransaction();
      const doc = await db.insurance
        .find({ session })
        .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
        .limit(1)
        .lean();
      const latest = doc[0];
      const payload = { ...params, id: latest ? latest.id + 1 : 1 };
      const data = await db.insurance.create(payload, { session });

      await mongoTransaction.commitWithRetry(session);
      const result = defaultResult('SuccessCreateInsurance', SuccessCreateInsurance[this.lang], data, 200);
      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      logger.log('error', 'ProductService-createInsurance', { error });
      throw error;
    } finally {
      await session.endSession();
    }
  }
```

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: is there a `.create` method on collection? I am aware of `.insertOne` & `.insertMany` both take 2nd parameter, which is `options`. Did you tried that one?

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.2/interfaces/InsertOneOptions.html
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.2/interfaces/BulkWriteOptions.html

Comment: @TamilVendhanKanagarasu I don't think that's the issue cause the error persists right on the .find method (I also tried findOne, didn't work)

Comment: Are you using native driver or some ORM like mongoose? For `.findOne`, `.find`, etc, session property must be passed in the 3rd parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out I have to pass session on the 3rd parameter on find method and wrap payload as an array on create method cause it can only take an array.
the code will look like this

```
async createInsurance(params) {
    const session = await db99.startSession();
    session.startTransaction();
    try {
      const doc = await db.insurance
        .findOne(null, null, { session })
        .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
        .limit(1)
        .lean();
      const latest = doc[0];
      const payload = { ...params, id: latest ? latest.id + 1 : 1 };
      const data = await db.insurance.create([payload], { session });

      await session.commitTransaction();
      const result = defaultResult('SuccessCreateInsurance', SuccessCreateInsurance[this.lang], data, 200);
      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      await session.abortTransaction();
      logger.log('error', 'ProductService-createInsurance', { error });
      throw error;
    } finally {
      await session.endSession();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [Model.create](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.create) indicates that the documents must be passed in an array in order to specify options:

> [options] «Object» Options passed down to save(). To specify options, docs must be an array, not a spread.

Change

```
const payload = { ...params, id: latest ? latest.id + 1 : 1 };
```

to

```
const payload = [{ ...params, id: latest ? latest.id + 1 : 1 }];
```